# Dimension of $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb C} \mathbb H$ as $\mathbb {R}$ vector space.

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, quaternions, division-algebras

On [page 15 of this note](https://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/Spin/Lecture2.pdf)

> $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb C} \mathbb H$ is an $8$-dimensional real vector space.

Is there a simple way to see this?

Comment: Exactly *where* does it say that?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Line -12 of page 15.

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb H$ is a $2$-dimensional $\mathbb C$ vector space, so $\operatorname{End}_\mathbb C(\mathbb H)\cong M_2(\mathbb C)$. The latter is, of course, is $8$ dimensional considered as an $\mathbb R$ vector space.